# How to use fgetcsv to get specific columns from a CSV?

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have an interesting piece of work to complete

I have a lot of spreadsheets which I have converted to CSV's - these spreadsheets started out as templates with a set number of columns.

Unfortunately over time people have added columns and removed them.

Is there a way I can adapt the following code to select certain column names from each CSV

```
foreach($fileinfos as $pathname => $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isFile()) continue;
      if(substr($pathname,-3) == 'csv'){

            $file = fopen($pathname, "r"); 
            while ($line = fgetcsv($file,0,'^','¬')){
               echo substr($pathname,56) .'   '.$numcols.'<br>';          
             }
            fclose($file);
      }
}
```

UPDATE:

Here is my array of accepted columns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Date Raised
    [1] => QA phase
    [2] => Item ID
    [3] => Screen Number
    [4] => Reason
    [5] => Matches originals?
    [6] => Issue / Comments
    [7] => Raise with Client?
    [8] => Raised By
    [9] => Status
    [10] => TP/AS Status Initials
    [11] => TP/AS Status  date
    [12] => TP/AS Status Comment
    [13] => Retested by
    [14] => Retested date
    [15] => Retested Comment
)
```

here is my array of avalible

```
Array
(
    [0] => Date Raised
    [1] => QA phase
    [2] => Item ID
    [3] => Screen Number
    [4] => exam 
    [5] => Reason
    [6] => Matches originals?
    [7] => Issue / Comments
    [8] => Raise with Client?
    [9] => Raised By
    [10] => Status
    [11] => TP/AS Status Initials
    [12] => TP/AS Status  date
    [13] => TP/AS Status Comment
    [14] => dd Comments
    [15] => PM Comments
    [16] => Retested by
    [17] => Retested date
    [18] => Retested Comment
)
```

Array combine dosnt work.

Comment: Is there a first line which determines the column names? You could read that first line and remember the column names to build an array on all following lines where the column name will be used as key in this new array

Comment: There is a first line with the column names - so are you saying parse the first line then build an array from that and use the key to skip certain columns?

Answer (score 4):

```
$file = fopen($pathname, 'r');
$headers = fgetcsv($file, 0, '^', '¬');

while ($line = fgetcsv($file, 0, '^', '¬')) {
    $line = array_combine($headers, $line);

    var_dump($line);
    // access specific fields using $line['columnName']
}
```

Comment: This only works so long as columns have not been added in the middle

Comment: What do you mean by that? What specifically is the problem you have with this solution?

Comment: @Rob I think you have to split your csv file and make single files for all schemas available. Adding a column in the middle is destroying the schema of the rows after them. Or you have to re-read the column names at the point where the schema changes.

Answer (score 3):

I would try something like this:

```
$csv = array();
$columnnames = fgetcsv($fp, 1024);
while (true == ($columns = fgetcsv($fp, 1024))) {
    $row = array_combine($columnnames, $columns);
    $csv[] = $row;
}
```

On a CSV file like this

```
id,name,email
1,benjamin,benjamin@example.com
2,rob,rob@example.com
```

the `$csv` variable should contain something like this:

```
1 => array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'benjamin',
    'email' => 'benjamin@example.com'
)
...
```